# Queue doesn't return correct values

Tags: c++, queue

So, basically I'm having an assignment, but that isn't the actual problem. The assignment requires me to use a list, which is fine so far.

So the idea is the following: I'm having a function which prints the contents of a directory recursively, which works fine, but now I'm trying to get each entry saved in a queue, which I'm later gonna use for something else. The nasty part is that I push each entry (the `d_name` from the `dirent` structure) into the queue in that function, and if I print the contents of the queue directly at the end of the function, it returns fine, but if I print the results in `main`, I get also garbage.

So my test directories look like this:

```
-DummyDir
    -DummyDir2
         -DummyDir6
         -DummyDir7
    -DummyDir3
         -DummyDir8
    -DummyDir4
         -DummyDir9
         -DummyDir10
    -DummyDir5
         -DummyDir11
         -DummyDir12
```

My function looks like this:

```
void dirwrap(char* dir, std::queue<char*>* queue)
{
   DIR* dirOpen;

   if(!(dirOpen = opendir(dir))){
     printf("Couldn't open directory: %s\n", dir);
     exit(-1);
   }

   struct dirent* dd;
   char path[2000];

   while ((dd = readdir(dirOpen)) != NULL)
   {
      if (strcmp(dd->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dd->d_name, "..") != 0) {

        //printf("%s\n", dd->d_name);
        queue->push(dd->d_name);        

        sprintf(path, dir, "%s", sizeof(dir));
        strcat(path, "/");
        strcat(path, dd->d_name);
        dirwrap(path, queue);
      }
  }
  closedir(dirOpen);
}
```

And if I print the contents of `queue` right after `closedir` I get a good result, like this:

```
DummyDir2
DummyDir6
DummyDir7
DummyDir5
DummyDir12
DummyDir11
DummyDir3 
DummyDir8
DummyDir4
DummyDir9
DummyDir10
```

But if I print the contents of my queue in `main`, I get this:

```
DummyDir2
DummyDir9
DummyDir10
DummyDir5
8�)�W▒
.
DummyDir3
~n��w▒
DummyDir4
DummyDir9
DummyDir10
```

I really can't seem to understand why is actually doing this, so I would really appreciate it if you would help me.

Comment: Any reason you aren't using `std::string`'s?

Comment: Not really, I just used std::queue as a test in C++, since I have to do the assignment in pure C, and I wanted to test if was having the same problem with std::queue, so I didn't really change to std::string.

Comment: @CatalinC you need to duplicate `dd->d_name` whatever the way, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

> ```
> while ((dd = readdir(dirOpen)) != NULL)
> {
>    if (strcmp(dd->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dd->d_name, "..") != 0) {
>
>      //printf("%s\n", dd->d_name);
>      queue->push(dd->d_name);
> ```

`dd->d_name` is an array inside the returned value, typically :

> ```
>      struct dirent {
>           ino_t          d_ino;       /* Inode number */
>           off_t          d_off;       /* Not an offset; see below */
>           unsigned short d_reclen;    /* Length of this record */
>           unsigned char  d_type;      /* Type of file; not supported
>                                          by all filesystem types */
>           char           d_name[256]; /* Null-terminated filename */
>       };
> ```

you need to duplicate it (e.g. *strdup* or use a std::string etc) because the data returned by `readdir()` may be overwritten by subsequent calls to `readdir()` for the same directory stream, and it will be freed by *closedir*

You are in C++ replace `std::queue<char*>* queue` by `std::queue<std::string>* queue` (or `std::queue<std::string> & queue`) or replace `queue->push(dd->d_name);` by `queue->push(strdup(dd->d_name));`

Comment: Thank you, using strdup worked. Oh, sorry about using char* there, I was just using std::queue to test if it was also causing me the same trouble as in C (using a queue implemented by me). If I was doing this in C++, I would have used std::string from the get go :)

Comment: Don't worry, I did.